# application crash on select video file from uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application i want to select the video from library by using UIImagePickerController. but when i select the video which has more than duration of 5 minute, my application is crash on ipod. how can i restrict the user to select the video which has duration more than 5 minute. please give me solution of this bug. Thank you.

Comment: please give some code. and what error is coming??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSURL * aUrlMovie = [[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] retain];/
 AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:aURLPath];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

Then add validation for the number of seconds you wish..

Comment: thanks for fast reply, i want to prevent the user to picking the video  before he/she press the choose butoon. can it's possible.

Comment: Yes @Victor, it is possible..... Put the above code in a method and call this method with a return type BOOL... If the seconds>=300 seconds.. flag a message in the ImagePickerDidFinsihPickingMediaWithInfo: method.

Comment: Check the below answer by Safecase

Answer (score 1):

```
 #pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate

  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
  {
NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ( [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
    self.mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum( mediaPath ) ) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum( mediaPath,
                                            self,
                                            @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                            NULL );
    } 
} 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **picker.videoMaximumDuration = 5;**

And something like this:

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
 #import <AVFoundation/AVAsset.h>

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   NSURL *selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:selectedVideoUrl];

   CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
  float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
  //NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
  if(seconds > 300)
  {
     [picker popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
  else{
  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

}